# Creating a tile map with nested arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm getting crazy with arrays so I need your help:

I created a couple of nested arrays:

```
private var mainArray:Array=[arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree];
private var arrayOne=[item1,item2,item3];
private var arrayTwo=[item4,item5,item6];
private var arrayThree=[item7,item8,item9];
```

First, when I try for example: `trace(mainArray[2][0])` Flash Builder's output is: undefined or null (instead of item7).

Second, I'm not able to find any row/col position (obviously...because every object seems to be undefined):

```
private function findPosition(row:int,col:int)
{
    for(var row:int=0;row<=mainArray.length;row++)
    {
      for(var col:int=0;col<=mainArray[row].length;col++
      {
           trace(row,col,mainArray[row][col]);
      }
    }
}
```

It always throws me some type of error (I tryied many self-made solutions and google searches).

I need to find every row/col position and place artworks according to it, I'm creating a tile map, and this may be the simplest way for me(beginner).

Thanks for every possible solution.

Comment: Just for the sake of terminology, you're referring to 2-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to populate the mainArray before the other Arrays have been created.
Move line 1 down to line 4.

```
private var arrayOne:Array = [item1,item2,item3];
private var arrayTwo:Array = [item4,item5,item6];
private var arrayThree:Array = [item7,item8,item9];
private var mainArray:Array = [arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree];
```

Comment: I tryied to move mainArray down, the output is always 'null', but I think the problem was another: My 'items' were Bitmaps. So I change them to String and it seems to work now. I thought arrays could contain bitmaps.

Comment: Arrays can contain anything. If you were getting null, you were most likely instantiating your bitmaps incorrectly.

Comment: [Embed(source="../folder/image.png")]
public static const Image:Class;

var tile:Bitmap=new Image() as Bitmap;

This is the way I create my instance. But now my problem is that I can't figure out how to show a determined tile according to position.

Comment: When do you instantiate your items? Perhaps it's the same issue as above, that you need to create the items before adding them into the Array. I would need to see more of your code.

Comment: I used a for loop to find the position and 'trace('tile placed');'. It seems to work as I see 12 'tile placed' in the output (my tiles are 12).

I only don't understand how can I assign a different position to every single tile, looping through the array.

Comment: private function rowColCount(row:int,col:int):void
 {

 for (var row:int=0;row<level.length;row++)
 {
     for (var col:int=0;col<level[row].length;col++)               
            {
             trace(row,col, level[row][col]); 
      trace('tileAdded'); 
     }
   
 }
   
 }

Answer (score 0):

you can create a 2-dimensional array all inline

```
private var mainArray:Array= [
      [item1,item2,item3],
      [item4,item5,item6],
      [item7,item8,item9]
];
```

or

```
private var mainArray:Array = new Array();
```

then in a method add the sub arrays

```
mainArray.push([item1,item2,item3]);
mainArray.push([item4,item5,item6]);
mainArray.push([item7,item8,item9]);
```